# Dynamically toggling imported css file in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a react ui library for one of my projects. The ui library does not have good support for changing the themes dynamically yet. So the only option i have is to create a new css file overriding the styles using selectors. Now I want to theme my app and i was wondering if there is a way to dynamically change the css file that is imported so that the theming works fine. I have multiple css files overriding the selectors with different colors and i need to import / apply these dynamically. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: @dfsq Can you tell me how to do it?